# RecyclerView adapter onItemClick event not triggering

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am a Java Android developer trying to re-learn RecyclerView adapters in Kotlin.

I have a Fragment that holds a RecyclerView. I initialized the adapter and the OnItemClickListener inside the Fragment class. However my onItemClick() is never triggered. The Log.d never shows.

BreakingNewsFragment.kt

```
class BreakingNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_breaking_news) {

lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter

val TAG = "BreakingNewsFragment"

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel
    setupRecyclerView()
    Log.d(TAG, "onitemclick") // this shows!

    newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "onitemclick") // this won't show
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putSerializable("article", it)
        }
        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment,
            bundle
        )
    }

    viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        when(response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                    newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.message?.let {message ->
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: $message")
                }
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                showProgressBar()
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun hideProgressBar() {
    paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}

private fun showProgressBar() {
    paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    newsAdapter = NewsAdapter()
    rvBreakingNews.apply {
        adapter = newsAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    }
}
}
```

NewsAdapter.kt

```
class NewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        // can't compare article IDs; articles from API do not have IDs. but URLs are unique for each article so we can compare those
        return oldItem.url == newItem.url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

// instead of using a standard list to store objects, use this ListDiffer to calculate differences between lists
val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
    return ArticleViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_article_preview, parent,false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val article = differ.currentList[position]
    holder.itemView.apply { // apply: reference views directly
        Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)
        tvSource.text = article.source.name
        tvTitle.text = article.title
        tvDescription.text = article.description
        tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
        setOnItemClickListener { onItemClickListener?.let( { it(article) }) }
    }
}

private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null // pass current article to function, open webview page from there

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Article) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `holder.itemView.apply {`, you're not assigning the callback to your holder.itemView; you're calling `setOnItemClickListener` which all it does is change your `onItemClickListener`, which is actually a local variable, not a callback function in the view.

What you want to do is:

```kotlin
holder.itemView.apply { // apply: reference views directly
        ..
        setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener?.let( { it(article) }) }
    }
```

(note, this is `setOnClickListener`, not `setOn*Item*ClickListener`)

I would suggest that you make `var onItemClickListener` not private, use that from outside the adapter directly, and remove `fun setOnItemClickListener()`... In the Kotlin world, public `var`s like that gets compiled to have their setters, so you don't really need Java style setters anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Once I have onItemClickListener as a public var, do I have to set it from the Fragment using  ' newsAdapter.apply { ... } ' ?

Comment: Yes, just like how you normally would use a setter.